# Ubuntu wont connect to upgraded WIFI

Tags: networking

Ubuntu 22 wont connect to our upgraded corporate WIFI, but will connect via cable. I dual boot  windows 11 for such occassions, and it connects fine. It has been suggested our (very agressive) firewall might be the cause. Other distros I tried will not connect.